# Can a user restore a deleted account?

Tags: discussion, new-users

Perhaps I shouldn't, but I feel a *little* bit bad for this guy.

He:

1. Asked a question on GameDev exchange that was migrated here:
2. Got an answer
3. For reasons unknown, deleted the account created here. (Could have happened before the answer was posted)
4. Re-posted the *same* question here.
5. I closed that question as a duplicate of the other one (since it had an answer).

Now he obviously made several mistakes. Even several large ones. However, it seems like the system has failed him a bit:

- He can't respond to the original answer since he deleted his account. Of course, if he gets 50 rep he can.
- He can't get *new* answers, since the question was (rightfully) closed as a duplicate.

So, assuming such a user realized his mistake, and wanted to fix the problem, what could he do? Could he potentially recover the old account?

Is there anything we can/should do to help prevent/fix this kind of sequence?

For reference, here are the two questions (**Note: I'm not trying to invoke the Meta effect here**):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27971618/remove-picturebox-during-runtime-c-sharp-net-windows-form?noredirect=1

[How can I remove / delete a picturebox during runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27971492/how-can-i-remove-delete-a-picturebox-during-runtime-c-sharp-windows-form)

Comment: I don't know for sure, but it looks to me like the GameDev account is still live, just unregistered. I would think if he registered on that account under the login he used for here, the accounts would merge in a way. I don't know if that would let him regain access to the SO question, but the GameDev version still shows on the unregistered account...

Comment: I'm not sure if it can be fixed but  check the [account recovery faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95358/i-lost-control-of-my-account-before-registering-can-it-be-recovered)

Comment: If a question is migrated to a different site, the migration doesn't create an account for the user. So I guess that the user [multipack1](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/59308/multipack1) didn't delete their account but didn't actually register on SO.

Comment: @TLama Huh, I thought it did. How does the original user get access to the question?

Comment: Flag and ask for a mod to merge his original question into the new one.

Comment: I don't know, but I believe it's not the first time this problem was hit. If the user now registers on SO, he will get a new, unique user ID, if I'm not mistaken. But who's the owner of the question?

Comment: related to this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7328/135695

Comment: He just needs to talk to his class mate that [asked a very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27967212/c-sharp-unload-and-load-form-hide-and-close).  I've seen several of them, looks like the teacher told them to find help at SO.

Comment: @HansPassant, to me, it does not look like a class mate. He have the same name: multipack1. So now he created 3 accounts and is posting very similar questions. http://stackoverflow.com/users/4459062/spaceships111, http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/59308/multipack1, http://stackoverflow.com/users/4454925/multipack1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, a user can delete and recreate their account as many times as they want, and that migrated question will get reattached to their account *every single time*, so long as they are using the same network profile that asked the question on the origin site. That's not the case here. They used different credentials to create the second Stack Overflow account, so the system wasn't able to connect the question to them. They could easily just create a new account with the same credentials as GameDev and they'd immediately have access to the question again.

A user *could* contact us and explain the situation if they want access to the question again, and we would probably merge the network accounts together and assign the question back to them.

Comment: I deleted few profiles. I do not want to restore them. I want the urls of the abandoned user profiles so that I can see the update on the questions. How can I get the urls of the deleted profile. How can I contact you?

Comment: Is this procedure (reassign the question ) works as of today ?