# Changed new account user email to old account email address

Tags: support, accounts, merge-accounts

Before everything else, I MESSED UP.

What I did:

1. I deleted my SE account over a disagreement about a question. (Realized my mistake once I deleted the account)
2. Created a new account with a different email and started fresh. Everything was going good.
3. I stumbled across this question in meta - [Can a user restore a deleted account?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283590/can-a-user-restore-a-deleted-account)
4. Since there was a way I could recover my account, rather than having two accounts, I decided to use one.
5. **I went ahead and changed the email for the new account to the email from old account. (Shouldn't have done this either)**

Now the end result:

1. I am trusted in a few sites which I joined using previous account. +100 rep in all the sites I joined using previous account as well as new account.
2. +100 rep in Stack Overflow which I honestly did not expect or deserve.

I was hoping

1. I would get the 2000+ rep which was accumulated in previous account. My old questions linked to my account.
2. OR I will remain in 163 rep from the new account which is also fair considering my atrocities.

Now I am curious about what happened. I had no malicious intent while doing this and I have no proof to that apart from my word. I just wanted my old questions / answers back. I can gain the rep over time.

What should be my course of action now?

Comment: The +100 came from association bonus once an account reach 200+ every other comunity account get +100. That's normal. But what is the 2000+ rep you are talking about?

Comment: Technically I did not gain 200+ rep in any site. When the account got merged, automatically +100 got awarded in stackoverflow; causing the same to happen everywhere. The previous account had 2000+ rep.

Comment: Account A has 20 So rep. Account B has 181 Sorep. when mergging A & B you get a total >= 200. That trigger the association bonus.

Comment: In my case, account A had 163. Account B (which was deleted) had 2000+ rep.

Comment: I'd try https://stackoverflow.com/contact. You may be in luck and an employee that can do something about it may notice this meta post and help you, but that's uncertain, and if you use the contact page an employee certainly will. There's a good chance this can get fixed, but only by an SE employee.

Comment: @ErikA Contact page requires two profiles for merge. I have only one where I modified the email address to old account. Can I go ahead with `other` category in contact?

Comment: @nightgaunt Of course. It's all manually reviewed by sensible humans, so I assume it will be fine, might take a little longer for them to get to it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the answer @ErikA. I contacted the Stack Overflow team as you mentioned. They said once the account is deleted, the questions / answers cannot be linked back to the any other account. Copying the exact response for future reference.

> As is explained when you delete your profile, we cannot restore
>   content from it when you decide to create a profile again. The
>   question you reference is talking about migrated questions
>   specifically, which can be glitchy and sometimes do not get attached
>   to accounts properly due to a variety of account issues.
>
> When you merged your accounts, you reconnected to a network account
>   that had the association bonus flag set to it, which is why you
>   received the 100 reputation bonus. Merging would not ever recover
>   content from a past deleted profile.
>
> Regards, Stack Overflow Team